# kali 2.0 it seems as though node was renamed nodejs

Tags: kali-linux, node.js

Im not sure why but the output from the commands are as follows. I have been trying to download npm but cant seem to. Was wondering if node was renamed at install due to naming conflict(wouldn't think so because node is not found but was always curious what would happen if two packages had the same name?) or if this is a bogus install package?

nodejs command works as expected. Brings up the JavaScript cli interface.

`node -v command not found.`

`nodejs -v v0.10.29`

Not sure what to do? Should I remove nodejs and reinstall. Advice is appreciated.

Update: I made a live usb and booted it. Ran the commands above. Same output. Im thinking that nodejs is a fork designed for kali. Not positive but comes pre-installed. I have decided not to remove it and to install node and npm separately.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was trying to run a module that had the below shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Then, I replaced it with that and it works

```
#!/bin/sh
':' //; exec "$(command -v nodejs || command -v node)" "${0}" "${@}"
```

I post this for those who had the same problem, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep all versions of any functional scripts.  Node.js and (1) are simple constructs, that hackers can easily exploit via sockets and elevated daemons, especially in Debian Kernels.  Very hard to see and clean, if written well...

But this javascript also uses the code-base to handle data-streams for indexing, log file writes or any other meta-data that Kali2 or Rolling collects.